# How to fix 'translate() got an unexpected keyword argument 'format''

Tags: python, google-translation-api

I face a problem when I translate text that return apostrophe like 
`en: "this is me" == fr: "c'est moi"`, but I get `" c&#39;est moi"`.
for that I want to specify the format to text, but when I execute the script I get:

```
TypeError: translate() got an unexpected keyword argument 'format'
```

```py
from google.cloud import translate

# Instantiates a client
translate_client = translate.Client()

# The text to translate
text = u'this is me'
# The target language
target = 'fr'

# Translates some text into Russian
translation = translate_client.translate(
    text,
    target_language=target, format='text')

print(u'Text: {}'.format(text))
print(u'Translation: {}'.format(translation['translatedText']))
```

Comment: The error seems to be correct. According to the [documentation](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/translate/usage.html) there is no keyword named `format`.

Comment: so how i can for the api to return the apostrophe

Comment: You can use `_format` not `format`.  It has a leading underscore. @Matthias check the code [here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/blob/master/translate/google/cloud/translate_v2/client.py#L186).

Comment: @user9477447 The return is correct by API and `format_` won't help you because it is for _input_ not _output_, but I provided a way to convert it for you below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to provide an argument for `format` you have to use `format_` which takes optional arguments: [[github code]](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/blob/8b183246398b92c277b2e6681a28fb62a10b47b2/translate/google/cloud/translate_v2/client.py#L186)

> :type format_: str
>
> > :param format_: (Optional) One of `text` or `html`, to specify if the input text is plain text or HTML.

However this is for *input text* not output text. If you want to convert back to a real apostrophe you could use `html.unescape` as what you are getting back is the html representation of the character: [[docs]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.html#html.unescape)

```py
import html
print(html.unescape(text))
```

Comment: Awesome. Let me know if you need anything else with it. :)